# Access is denied error System.DirectoryServices SSIS

Tags: ssis, directoryservices

I'm doing something I think is pretty straight forward.  Attempting to update AD attributes from an SSIS task.  So I am connecting to AD, reading data from the SSIS stream, writing the data to attributes and calling CommitChanges.

When I do the CommitChanges I receive the Access is denied error.

I have checked the user has AD update rights. In ADSI Edit, I can update attributes.

One other thing that might be causing the issue.  The user is in DomainA and I attempting to update an AD account in DomainB.

Any help, would be appreciated.

Comment: UserA, in DomainA, is communicating with DomainB to update UserB which resides in that domain. UserA has sufficient permissions in DomainB to perform this task. A manual execution of your script results in success. Execution from SSIS results in failure. <- If all of that is true, then you need to examine the context from which SSIS is executing. Is this a SQL Agent job? If so, is this running under a stored credential or is the SQL Agent itself running as UserA?

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to wrap my head around what you wrote.  What you are saying is that the SSIS job is running under the context of a specific user regardless of the user I use to connect to the LDAP destination. User A in Domain A is specified in the code as login to update User B in Domain B.  The program is run by User C in Domain A.  User C and User A both need update rights to Domain B.  is that right?